# Why am I getting error 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.utils.I18n.init' when call CryptoFactory.getInstance() method?

Tags: java, wss4j

I'm using wss4j version 2.1.2 to do xml digital signatures and attach to the soap header.

I have the following code and I get an error that a method doesn't exist ... but it does exist. In IntelliJ I can navigate to the location and the method is there but for some reason it's not finding it: *java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.utils.I18n.init*

```
public void initSettings() {   
    try {
        crypto =  CryptoFactory.getInstance();
    } catch (WSSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As requested, here is the complete error stack trace:

```
    at com.pilotfish.eip.modules.http.ws2.WSSecurityProcessor2.processData(WSSecurityProcessor2.java:182)
    at com.pilotfish.eip.transact.stages.ProcessorStage.process(ProcessorStage.java:44)
    at com.pilotfish.eip.transact.StageHandler.process(StageHandler.java:99)
    at com.pilotfish.eip.transact.Transaction.runStage(Transaction.java:117)
    at com.pilotfish.eip.transact.Transaction.flushQueue(Transaction.java:89)
    at com.pilotfish.eip.transact.Transaction.run(Transaction.java:78)
    at com.pilotfish.eip.gui.console.testing.TestingManager$TestingTransactionFramework$1.run(TestingManager.java:663)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.utils.I18n.init(Ljava/util/ResourceBundle;)V
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.WSProviderConfig.initializeResourceBundles(WSProviderConfig.java:199)
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.WSProviderConfig.init(WSProviderConfig.java:65)
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.CryptoFactory.<clinit>(CryptoFactory.java:39)
    at com.pilotfish.eip.modules.http.ws2.WSSecurityProcessor2.initSettings(WSSecurityProcessor2.java:140)
    at com.pilotfish.eip.modules.http.ws2.WSSecurityProcessor2.processData(WSSecurityProcessor2.java:155)
    ... 7 more
```

I'm seeing this, which might clue in on what the issue is:

### File: WSProviderConfig.java

```
private static void initializeResourceBundles() {
    I18n.init(new WSS4JResourceBundle());
}
```

But it's expecting String, String not WSS4JResourceBundle().

Comment: Can you post your complete error stack trace?

Comment: Updated with complete error stack trace

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522190

Comment: So the suggested duplicate doesn't answer my question. It tells me what is probably the issue but it doesn't tell me how to resolve it. Thanks for the stifle though.

Comment: @BrianTHannan Did you ever find and anwer to this?

Comment: Anyone able to resolve this issue?