# What are the libraries I need for CXF and WSS4J?

Tags: java, soap, cxf, wss4j

I'm trying to send a SOAP Request with authentication.
I'm using CXF to create the classes I need to call the web service.
And I found out I needed to use wss4j to add the authentication information in the header of the SOAP envelope. (I'm following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599983/ws-security-usernametoken-with-apache-cxf))
But I'm struggling with the libraries I have to include my project to make it work.

First I included the `org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:3.1.9` with maven.
To be able to use the Client, ClientProxy and Endpoint classes.

And then, I tried to include the `org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:1.6.19` with maven, to use the WSS4JInInterceptor and WSS4JOutInterceptor classes. But they aren't in that library.

So, if someone could tell me which library I have to use?

**EDIT**: I finally found the library I needed to use the WSS4J Interceptors.
It was `org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:3.1.11` but I had to download the jar from mvnrepository because IntelliJ IDEA wasn't able to find it...

But now I have another problem... I got this Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.utils.I18n.init(Ljava/util/ResourceBundle;)V
```

I read I had to add `org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-common` library but it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522190/cxf-wss4j-maven-nosuchmethod-error

Comment: I tried to use a previous version of CXF... it doesn't work...
I tried to compile the version 2.X.X of WSS4J... It doesn't compile...
Why is it so difficult to use those damn libraries...